# How to can I get a reference to an object an iterator points too?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a reference from an iterator but it does not seem possible. Therefore I'll ask the best.

```
class foo { public: void go() { } };

std::vector<foo> l;
std::vector<foo>::iterator iter = l.begin(), end = l.end();
while (iter != end)
{
    //foo& f  = iter;
    //foo& f2 = &iter;
    //foo& f3 = (foo&)iter;
    f.go();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get a reference to an iterator, or a reference to the object the iterator points to?

Comment: @juanchopanza: the object it points too

Comment: Then you should change the title!

Comment: So underestemated, a title. Changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to dereference the iterator.

```
foo &f = *iter;
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to dereference the iterator, since it has pointer semantics:

```
foo& f = *iter;
```

Comment: Accepting the answer of programmerjake, he needs the rep more then you. Thou a +1 for being faster.